# Filter json with set and map using nested attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, filter

I am working with some json returned via an API call and trying to figure if it's possible to filter one json object based on the values from another.  I came across set and map which is close, but not sure how to handled the nested attributed... here is a simplified example:

```
var teachers = [
{id: 1, name : 'Bob',studentid: []},
{id: 2, name : 'Sue',studentid: []},
{id: 3, name : 'Jean',studentid: []},
{id: 4, name : 'Jim',studentid: [
    "500zz"
]},
{id: 5, name : 'Paul',studentid: [
    "100zz",
    "120zz",
    "130zz"
]}
];

var students = [
{_id: "100zz", name : 'Betty'},
{_id: "120zz", name : 'Bob'},
{_id: "500zz", name : 'Billy'}
];

console.log(
  teachers.filter(
    (set => item => set.has(item.studentid))(new Set(students.map(item => item._id)))
  )
)
```

I would like the result to include only the teachers Jim and Paul ( with all associated data )... not sure what I need to add or do?  The array of studentid's is throwing me for a loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const teachers = [
  { id: 1, name: "Bob", studentid: [] },
  { id: 2, name: "Sue", studentid: [] },
  { id: 3, name: "Jean", studentid: [] },
  { id: 4, name: "Jim", studentid: ["500zz"] },
  { id: 5, name: "Paul", studentid: ["100zz", "120zz", "130zz"] }
];

const students = [
  { _id: "100zz", name: "Betty" },
  { _id: "120zz", name: "Bob" },
  { _id: "500zz", name: "Billy" }
];

// Filter teachers with students greater than 0.
const filtered = teachers.filter(x => x.studentid.length > 0);

// Map teachers with Students
const teachersWithStudents = filtered.map(x => {
  const stu = students
    .map(student => {
      // Determine whether or not teacher 'studentid' contains student '_id'
      const hasStudent = x.studentid.includes(student._id);
      // Teacher has student
      if (hasStudent) {
        return {
          id: student._id,
          name: student.name
        };
      }
      // Teacher does not have student
      return false;
    })
    .filter(x => x); // filter objects that are not false
  // Return teacher object with student (stu) objects
  return {
    ...x,
    studentid: stu
  };
// Return those with matches only
}).filter(x => x.studentid.length > 0);

console.log(teachersWithStudents);
```

Comment: Thanks for this...Close!  In testing this out with some real data it seems that a teacher will get returned even if there is no matching students... for example in Paul's case he always gets returned because his studentid array is not empty even in the case where there are no matching students in the students list.

Comment: In that case you can just add another filter to `teachersWithStudents` - `.filter(x => x.studentid.length > 0);`